# Как очистить файл с php кодом от специальных символов (открывающий и закрывающий теги)

Tags: php

Задача на самом деле на первый взгляд элементарная, но в самом файле строковые константы например, могут содержать в себе эти символы, к примеру.

Вот собственно и все вопрос. Заранее благодарю за варианты решения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents(__FILE__));
$output = '';

foreach ($tokens as $token) {

    if (!is_array($token)) {
        $output .= $token;
        continue;
    }

    switch ($token[0]) {
        case T_OPEN_TAG:
        case T_CLOSE_TAG:
            break;
        default:
            $output .= $token[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Ilya Pirogov, спасибо вам. Не знал об этой функции, изучил вопрос, работает просто супер.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
$code = preg_replace('/<\?(?:php)?|\?>/i','',$code);
```

Так мы удаляем все `<?`, `<?php` и `?>` из текста.

Тоже самое, но с обычной заменой:

```
$code = str_replace( array('<?php','<?','?>'), '', $code );
```

Comment: Я бы хотел найти варинт, чтобы вырезало все внутренние теги тоже, но покачто ограничелся только тем что вырезает порвый и последний. Ваш вариант смыкнул первый и тот что был закрывающий в строковой константе, тоисть ваш вариант корректно не сработал. Если есть вариант как учесть факт что это не закрывающий тег а всего лишь текстовое значение, было бы здорово.

Comment: Я уже несколько раз обновил ответ, проверьте последние вариант) <br>
А насчёт текстового значения, это достаточно сложно) но можно попробовать)

Comment: Объясню более подробно.

У нас есть класс, я хочу его сжать перед использованием.

Вот метод класса.
> $code =
> public function php($file)
>    {
>        $code = php_strip_whitespace($file);
>        $code = preg_replace("/^[\s]{1,}/m", "", $code);        
>        $code = preg_replace("!^<\?php(.*?)\?>$!si","\\1",$code);
>        $code = str_replace("defined('ALEXA')?:alexa_exit();",'',$code);
>        return $code;
>    } 
Если сделать так как предлагаете вы то оно запорит регулярку в preg_replace. Вот собственно корень проблемы.

Comment: Первая часть комментария относилась к
>>> Ваш вариант смыкнул первый и тот что был закрывающий
А насчёт этого - была 2 часть комментария

Comment: Ладно, спасибо за варианты буду пробовать на свежую голову.

Comment: Попробовал сделать RegExp - слишком сложное выражение получается, лучше просто сделать так:

    $code = str_replace( '<', '&lt;', $code );

Answer (score 0):

Одним словом, так и не дождавшись помощи экспертов, смолотил нечто вроде этого.

> $code =
> preg_replace("!^<?php(.*?)?>$!si","\1",$code);

Если есть идеи более изящные, буду рад помощи.